# How to make this script async?

Tags: asynchronous, google-analytics

I am trying to make my scripts async, as recommended by google.  I was wondering how to make the following script async:

```
 <script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-00000000-1');
</script>
```

Where to I put the async parameter???

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand the question. What you want to make asynch is the loading in the tracking script, not the function call, and that's already part of the tracking snippet:

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXXX-X"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-xxxxx-X');
</script>
```